# building opencv 2.2 under windows

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to get OpenCV working under windows 7. I am able to generate the visual studio solution file with cMake, but when I build the project in both release and debug mode, I get an error at the very end that says 
"unable to start program C:\opencv2.2\vs2010\release\all_build"
I also don't see cv200d.lib, cvaux200d.lib, etc being generated, so I can't compile any projects using OpenCV. I'd appreciate some help with this, or at least a link to a good tutorial for installing 2.1 or 2.2 under windows. Apparently the process has changed a bit from 2.0 and the willow garage wiki really isn't too helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using OpenFrameworks and it worked the first time. I know it doesn't have 100% of the stuff the full version of OpenCV has, but it works for now, and most importantly, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are trying to run one of the example projects, the problem is that you need to select the specific project you want to run as the start up project.

Project >> Properties

Under 'Common Properties' select 'Startup Project'

Select single startup project

Select your desired example project.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a detailed reference which walks you through each step of building OpenCV 2.2 on Windows 7:
http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/03/22/how-to-build-opencv-2-2-with-gpu-cuda-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should look to the detail compiler output. It should contain an explanation of happened errors. The most probable problem - some library wasn't build successfully.
Try re-configure OpenCV and disable build samples, tests and python support.

Also, if you are getting the "unable to start program C:\opencv2.2\vs2010\release\all_build" message, it indicates that you are trying to "Run" ALL_BUILD project instead of just "BUILD".

If you provide more detailed compiler output i will be able to say more clearly what's wrong.

Comment: I fixed the problem with cMake. When I compile, I'm not getting any errors (simply building instead of pressing the green triangle fixed that) but when I look in C:\opencv2.2\vs2010\release\, I'm not seeing any of the libraries that are supposed to have been generated there (cv200d.lib, cvaux200d.lib, etc). I'm following an tutorial for an old version of opencv, so I guess the real question is are those files even supposed to be there? If they are, do you know of a more recent tutorial for getting it all set up?

Comment: lib files are expected to be placed in the <BuildDir>/lib/ directory. dll files - <BuildDir>/bin. To get OpenCV headers make "Install" target and grab them from the <BuildDir>/include.